# Android GCM MeasurementBrokerService eats too much memory

Tags: android, memory-management, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented push notifications in my project according to [latest tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

My app has 2 background services running.
When I look into RAM memory, which my app occupies, I see (for instance):
 - total memory used **117 Mb**
 - memory used by app **13 Mb**
 - Google play services (com.google.android.gms) - **104 Mb (!)**.
And it written below, that service MeasurementBrokerService is in usage.

What am I doing wrong?
Why push notifications need so much memory?
What is this MeasurementBrokerService, is it possible to disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

on the start of your AndroidManifest add this line: xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="cl.datacomputer.alejandrob.example"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

and inside of the Application add this service tag:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        tools:replace="android:enabled"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

It's not a good solution, I know, but you can disable the service that causes the memory leak.

Sorry if my English is bad.

Regards.

Alejandro Burgos.

Comment: It was nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

Dublicate question here: ["Service MeasurementBrokerService is in use" is showing in my application process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336751/service-measurementbrokerservice-is-in-use-is-showing-in-my-application-proces)

Here is my answer to both.

I got rid of this service and couple of others by removing

```
NotificationCompat.Builder
...
startForeground(mNotificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

from my backround service.

For some reason. Alejandros solution did not work for me.